# Google App Engine - force Content-Length instead

Tags: google-app-engine, google-appengine-node

I am trying to "force" app engine to serve Content-Length instead of Transfer-Encoding but I can't figure it out.

I have a Node Express app running on flex engine.

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to force the headers as these headers are managed by App Engine (even if you modify them, at the end, app engine will select the correct values). Here I believe the option will be to do as mentioned at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference/request-response-headers?hl=fr#headers_added) and try to Compress the content as it is mentioned that app engine will use the header after compression, if compression is applied.

Comment: Thanks for response, I have added a compression to my responses (that added a `Content-Encoding: gzip` to header) but nothing seems to have changed :|

Answer (score 0):

It seems that setting `Content-Type` as `text/json` has "fixed" the problem - App engine sets the `Content-Length` header property.